# onpropertychange for a textbox in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, events, firefox, dom, mutation-events

How to handle the `onpropertychange` for a textbox in Firefox using JavaScript?

Below is an example:

```
var headerBGColorTextBox = document.getElementById('<%= tbHeaderBGColor.ClientID %>');

if (headerBGColorTextBox != null) {
  headerBGColorTextBox.pluggedElement = document.getElementById('<%= trHeaderBG.ClientID %>');
  headerBGColorTextBox.onpropertychange = function() {
    alert('function called');
    if (event.propertyName == 'style.backgroundColor' && event.srcElement.pluggedElement != null)
      alert(event.propertyName);
    event.srcElement.pluggedElement.style.backgroundColor = event.srcElement.style.backgroundColor;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to mimic the onpropertychange event, Mutation events as mentioned above that should work equally across modern browsers and the "object.watch" non-standard method that will provide support for old versions of FF < 3.

See documentation on MDC.

[Object.watch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch)

[Mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM_Events)

Comment: OBJECT.watch will not track DOM element changes. You have to use DOMAttrModified mutation event in W3C compliant browsers. OBJECT.watch is for trackign property changes on object you've created in Javascript only.

Answer (score 4):

It appears as if the `onpropertychange` event is IE Specific: http://www.aptana.com/reference/html/api/HTML.event.onpropertychange.html.

However, with that said, Firefox, at least 3.0.10 does support an event called "DOMAttrModified". The following is a snippet of how it works:

```
document.body.addEventListener("DOMAttrModified", function () { console.log ("Args: %o", arguments); }, false);
document.body.id = "Testing";
```

Where `console.log` is the assuming the Firefox extension [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) is installed.

Comment: DOMAttrModified is also supported by IE9 and Opera(7+). Still doesn't work in webkit as of August 2011.

Comment: @nix: Still no news for WebKit? Do you know what they plan to support this kind of use case?

Answer (score 2):

`onpropertychange` is non-standard.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536956

Answer (score 1):

The following code works:

```
var foo = '<%= tbHeaderBGColor.ClientID %>';

function changetext() 
  {
  alert('function called');
  if (event.propertyName == 'style.backgroundColor' && event.srcElement.pluggedElement != null)
    alert(event.propertyName);

  event.srcElement.pluggedElement.style.backgroundColor = event.srcElement.style.backgroundColor;
  }

if (!!document.addEventListener)
  {
  document.getElementById(foo).addEventListener("DOMAttrModified", changetext, false);
  }
else
  {
  document.getElementById(foo).addBehavior("foo.htc");
  document.getElementById(foo).attachEvent("onpropertychange", changetext);
  }
```

[DOM Mutation Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-MutationEvent-attrChange)